# Sass não compila caracter especial

Tags: sass, unicode

Tenho um ::after no meu código sass com o content "m²", a questão é que depois de compilado o ² vira erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele está imprimindo em UTF-8 (@charset "UTF-8";), realmente não entendo o motivo do erro.

Comment: Eu estava com dificuldade de encontrar o código do caracter especial, ai achei um conversor de caracteres especiais online. Segue o link, caso seja útil pra mais alguém: http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenho uma resposta que pode te ajudar. Ela não resolve o bug de compilação, *mas resolve a questão do número sobrescrito no `content`*.

Repare o `content:""` do elemento `::after` pode receber caracteres em `unicode`, mas para resolver isso vc pode usar o código `unicode` do caractere substituindo o `"m²"` por `"m\00B2"`. *Assim vc evita o caractere especial e usa o apenas o código unicode do caractere*.

Veja como fica executando o exemplo. E teste para ver se passa no compilador do SASS (acredito que vai funcionar!)

```css
span::after {
    content: "m\00B2" ;
}
```

```html
<span>num: </span>
```

Aqui tem uma tabela de caracteres sobrescrito e subscrito `unicode` que pode te interessar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block

Comment: Caaara, funcionou. Pra mim já é o bastante!! hahaha' Eu tinha tentado por o código do caracter, mas acho peguei de uma tabela errada. Obrigada! :)

Comment: @ThaviLang legal que resolveu, se vc quiser usar o 3 por exemplo o código é `\00B3`, mas vc pode consultar a tabela do link que lá tem mais algumas opções! Boa sorte ai []´s